JoinList statement runtime error 4605 This command is not available
#This is the code that I am running.
    Sub joinThisParagraphToList()
        Dim prgh As Paragraph
        
        Debug.Print Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString & " " & Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
        Debug.Print xlateWdListType(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListType)
        Debug.Print xlateWdListType(Selection.Paragraphs(2).Range.ListFormat.ListType)
        Set prgh = Selection.Paragraphs(1)
        Debug.Print "<" & prgh.Range.Text & ">"
        prgh.JoinList
        Set prgh = Nothing
    End Sub
    
    Private Function xlateWdListType(ByVal typ As WdListType) As String
        If typ = wdListBullet Then
            xlateWdListType = "wdListBullet"
        ElseIf typ = wdListListNumOnly Then
            xlateWdListType = "wdListListNumOnly"
        ElseIf typ = wdListMixedNumbering Then
            xlateWdListType = "wdListMixedNumbering"
        ElseIf typ = wdListNoNumbering Then
            xlateWdListType = "wdListNoNumbering"
        ElseIf typ = wdListOutlineNumbering Then
            xlateWdListType = "wdListOutlineNumbering"
        ElseIf typ = wdListPictureBullet Then
            xlateWdListType = "wdListPictureBullet"
        ElseIf typ = wdListSimpleNumbering Then
            xlateWdListType = "wdListSimpleNumbering"
        Else
            xlateWdListType = "unknown"
        End If
    End Function

The output from the debug.print statements is:
        11 XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX Hello
        
        wdListOutlineNumbering
        wdListOutlineNumbering
        <XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX Hello
        >

The problem that I am trying to solve is that what looks like an outline numbered list (1. 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, etc.) is actually several lists and they are not all using the automatic numbering features of MS Word.
Some of the paragraphs were numbered by Word and some were manually inserted by other users.  I run into this issue 10 or 15 times a year and have to spend several hours just correcting the numbering in a document so future maintenance of the document is simplified.  I am attempting to find at least a semi-automated way to discover and correct these issues.
I have two paragraphs in the document both are outline numbered 11. and 11.1.  Paragraph 11.1 is immediately after 11 and both ore only 1 line long.  The problem is that the two paragraphs are NOT items in the same list.  My understanding of the JoinList statement is that it should basically take the paragraph, identified by prgh in my code (i.e. paragraph 11.), and make it part of the nearest list in the document, which in this case would be the very next line (i.e. paragraph 11.1).  Before starting the macro code above, I have paragraph 11 selected.
My problem is that I am getting a runtime error of 4605 and nothing I have found online discussing 4605 is talking about the JoinList statement and I have not been able to find anything more that the basic MS Word object model reference information; nothing about what the error really means in my case or how to fix or code around it.
I have the entire document that I can provide as an example, but I don’t see any way to attach a document.

It could be related to the fact that there is only one paragraph in the selection.  Try passing in the paragraph reference as a parameter to the jointhisparagraphtolist method.

Outline lists can get really messy. My suggestion is to use (for instance) left indent as a way to determine list level and to process everything rather than trying splice in individual items. For simplicity I'm going to assume that you only need to look at List Paragraphs, but this approach could be expanded to test whatever. I also didn't add anything to trim hardcoded numbers, and I picked an outline style more or less at random.
Sub fixOutlineList()
    Dim listPara As Paragraph
    Dim outlineList As ListTemplate
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Define an outline list template
    Set outlineList = Document.ListTemplates.Add(OutlineNumbered:=True)
    For i = 1 To 3
        With outlineList.ListLevels(i)
            .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
            .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
            .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
            .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
            .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1)
            .TabPosition = InchesToPoints(1)
            .ResetOnHigher = 0
            .StartAt = 1
            .ResetOnHigher = True
        End With
    Next i
    outlineList.ListLevels(1).NumberFormat = "%1"
    outlineList.ListLevels(2).NumberFormat = "%1.%2"
    outlineList.ListLevels(3).NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3"
    
    ' Loop through the list paras in the doc using
    ' left indent to determine list level
    For Each listPara In Document.ListParagraphs
        Select Case listPara.LeftIndent
        Case 36
           Call setListLevel(listPara, 1, outlineList)
        Case 72
            Call setListLevel(listPara, 2, outlineList)
        Case 96
             Call setListLevel(listPara, 3, outlineList)
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "no case for indent " & listPara.LeftIndent
        End Select
    Next listPara
End Sub
Sub setListLevel(listPara As Paragraph, level As Integer, outlineList As ListTemplate)
    ' get rid of existing indents and tabs just
    ' to normalize everything
    With listPara
        .Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
        .TabStops.ClearAll
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .LeftIndent = 0
    End With
    ' try to explictly set the list level if one already exists
    ' this can throw an error when (I think) a preceding level
    ' can't be determined
    On Error Resume Next
    listPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = level
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "unable to establish an item for level preceding " & level
        Err.Clear
    End If
    ' apply the list template and set the list level
    listPara.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:=outlineList, ContinuePreviousList:=True, ApplyLevel:=level
    ' I've found there are times when you need to add this step again at the end
    listPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = level
End Sub

